# FOSUserBundle Registration and Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, modal-dialog, fosuserbundle

I have a little problem with FOSUserBundle and the Bootstrap Modal.

When i try ton send my form from /register it works fine but when i try to do the same thing on my modal(which isn't on /register) i have nothing on my database :/
It seems to be the same on all my pages except /register

Thank you for helping me.

I use on my register_content:

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

    <div class="well">

        {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register, form-horizontal'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.username, "form.username", {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}

            {{ form_errors(form.username) }}

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{ form_widget(form.username, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.email, "form.email", {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}

            {{ form_errors(form.email) }}

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.firstname, "form.firstname", {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}

            {{ form_errors(form.firstname) }}

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{ form_widget(form.firstname, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.lastname, "form.lastname", {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}

            {{ form_errors(form.lastname) }}

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{ form_widget(form.lastname, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.birthday, "form.birthday", {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}

            {{ form_errors(form.birthday) }}

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{ form_widget(form.birthday, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.address, "form.address", {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}

            {{ form_errors(form.address) }}

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{ form_widget(form.address, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.address2, "form.address2", {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}

            {{ form_errors(form.address2) }}

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{ form_widget(form.address2, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.zipcode, "form.zipcode", {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}

            {{ form_errors(form.zipcode) }}

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{ form_widget(form.zipcode, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.city, "form.city", {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}

            {{ form_errors(form.city) }}

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{ form_widget(form.city, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div><br>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first, "form.plainPassword.first", {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}

            {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second, "form.plainPassword.second", {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}

            {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.second) }}

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">{{ 'registration.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</button>
        </div>
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </div>
```

And on my view i have:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="registerModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="registerModalLabel">S'inscrire</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {% render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register')) %}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Fermer</a>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Tell me if you need more informations

Edit: Rendered html form

```
<div class="modal fade" id="registerModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="registerModalLabel">S'inscrire</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">


<div class="well">
    <h2>Informations requises</h2><br>

    <form name="fos_user_registration_form" method="post" action="" class="fos_user_registration_register, form-horizontal">


    <h4>Informations générales</h4><br>
    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label required" for="fos_user_registration_form_username">Nom d&#039;utilisateur</label>



        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_username" name="fos_user_registration_form[username]" required="required" placeholder="John69" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label required" for="fos_user_registration_form_email">Email</label>



        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_email" name="fos_user_registration_form[email]" required="required" placeholder="john@rambo.com" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="fos_user_registration_form_paypal">Compte Paypal</label>



        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="email" id="fos_user_registration_form_paypal" name="fos_user_registration_form[paypal]" placeholder="john@test.com" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="fos_user_registration_form_firstname">Prénom</label>



        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_firstname" name="fos_user_registration_form[firstname]" placeholder="John" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="fos_user_registration_form_lastname">Nom</label>



        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_lastname" name="fos_user_registration_form[lastname]" placeholder="Rambo" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="fos_user_registration_form_birthday">Date de naissance</label>



        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="input-append date datepicker"><input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_birthday" name="fos_user_registration_form[birthday]" placeholder="aaaa-mm-jj" class="form-control" /><label for="fos_user_registration_form_birthday" class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></label></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h4>Informations de localisation</h4><br> 

    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="fos_user_registration_form_address">Adresse</label>



        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_address" name="fos_user_registration_form[address]" placeholder="Place Bellecour" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="fos_user_registration_form_address2">Adresse complémentaire</label>



        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_address2" name="fos_user_registration_form[address2]" placeholder="Appartement 25" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode">Code postal</label>



        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_zipcode" name="fos_user_registration_form[zipcode]" placeholder="69000" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="fos_user_registration_form_city">Ville</label>



        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" id="fos_user_registration_form_city" name="fos_user_registration_form[city]" placeholder="Lyon" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div><br>

    <h4>Informations de sécurité</h4><br>
    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label required" for="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_first">Mot de passe</label>



        <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="password" id="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_first" name="fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][first]" required="required" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label required" for="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_second">Confirmation</label>



        <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="password" id="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_second" name="fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][second]" required="required" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 15px;" type="submit">Enregistrer</button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="fos_user_registration_form__token" name="fos_user_registration_form[_token]" value="hzBzyrbMSn1Ep0r6QAfQxAfqwceJhBRPbohNEi_wW8Q" />
</div>                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Fermer</a>
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="Enregistrer" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You say there's nothing in the DB - what is the behaviour of the web page?

Comment: What do you mean? I tried on my homepage. There is nothing else than the header (with login and register modal) and footer. When i send the form, i see on the profiler that nothing is send. But i'm not sure that i have understand your question because i'm french sorry

Comment: I mean: you say it doesn't work; is there any other evidence that it doesn't work apart from no data in the DB?  Does the form submission appear to succeed, with no errors, exactly the same as when you do it from /register?

Comment: Oh ok, no, profiler says "This form was not submitted.", but i have not errors on my console for anything else

Comment: I'd try to narrow it down to a) the modal or b) the URL - can you try the modal on /register, or a non-modal normal form on some other URL?

Comment: On a non-modal form it's not working too. On /register with modal  nothing load (blank page) and without i have all my form which works

Comment: The FOSUserBundle `/register` route is (typically) set up in `routing.yml`, and only that route will process the form submission.  Are you changing that, or just rendering `FOSUserBundle:Registration:register` on a different URL?  Could you post the rendered HTML of the form?

Comment: I just rendering FOSUserBundle:Registration:register. I put the rendered html on my first post

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is here, in your rendered form:

```
<form name="fos_user_registration_form" method="post" action="" class="fos_user_registration_register, form-horizontal">
```

The `action=""` means in HTML4 that the form will submit back to the same URL it's on, so if you're anywhere other than `/register` then it won't work.  In HTML5 it's officially not allowed.

I've checked my own registration form, and the `action` explicitly contains the registration route, it's not blank.  Probably yours is blank because you're rendering the result of a Controller Action without passing it a Request - it doesn't know how it's being called, so it can't put the correct Route in the `action` attribute.

As for how to resolve this, what you need to be able to do is render the form, but control the action independently.  As is, you're rendering the result of the entire `registerAction`, so you have no flexibility.  I don't know of an official way of doing this, but an option could be to make your own Action which mimics what happens in the existing FOSUserBundle `RegistrationController` ([source on GitHub](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php)), something like this:

*Controller*

```
class EkynoxRegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();

        return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

*NB you may need to copy more here, I've assumed that we don't need to create any User objects or handle the Request, because this page is only for initial submission of data to the main page*

*Template*

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('fos_user_register'), 'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register, form-horizontal'}}) }}
```

And then call that Action where you want to display the form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So i have override the RegistrationController with your pasted code but they say that i can't call method SetAction on Class... I don't know why because i see on the original registration form they are doing this:         `$form->setData($user);`
so it should be the same thing with SetAction right? I don't need to put more code for now?

Comment: When you say you "override" it, what did you actually do?  I was suggesting simply adding that new `EkynoxRegistrationController` to your app, and then setting up a route which points to it.

Comment: Well, i have recreated a RegistrationController (i had just one on my fos vendors before) on my userbundle, i guess it was what you wanted? `Attempted to call method "setAction" on class "Symfony\Component\Form\Form" in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/src/Website/UserBundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php line 26`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - you have to call `setAction` on the `FormBuilder` (which is in the default Symfony `FormFactory` in this case, so we can't do it).  So instead you can [set the `action` value when you start the form in the View](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-method-of-a-form), I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure about `'action': path('fos_user_register')`? Because they say a such route does not exist so i tried with `fos_user_registration_register` and i haven't error. But when i push the validate button, it's redirecting me to /register and nothing is send to my database :/

Comment: You're right about the route name, I was getting it from `routing.yml` when it should be from `registration.xml` in the UserBundle config.  As for the end result, there's not much to go on.  Any errors?

Comment: When i open my modal i have `[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (registerModal, line 0)` and when i click on the error and i have `No route found for &quot;GET /registerModal/&quot; (from &quot;http://localhost/website/web/app_dev.php&quot;) (404 Not Found)`. I tried to change my route on all.xml (i know it's bad but it was just a test) and i haven't error after this, but it's the same probleme, redirecting to /register and nothin on database.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what else to suggest.  Perhaps include more of the original Controller?  Also I'd have a vague worry about the standard Symfony CSRF protection when moving between URLs, although I think it should work since you're using the standard FOSUserBundle Form on both pages.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you frumious,

Thanks to you I found the answer, in fact, i had to add the `if ($form->isValid()) {}` condition and the confirmedAction (the same as the FOSUserRegistrationController) on my RegistrationController.

Don't know exactly why but it works now so a BIG thank you and sorry, I can't give you some points because i haven't enough reputation at this time :/